# cast a List to a Collection

Tags: java, list, collections

i have some pb. I want to cast a List to Collection in java

```
Collection<T> collection = new Collection<T>(mylList);
```

but i have this error

> Can not instantiate the type Collection

Comment: I advice you to read a book about the basis of java. Collection is an interface, not a class. Understanding the different goals of both is important.

Comment: @extraneon +1 Was about to suggest the same thing. Using collections without a proper understanding of the basics is not a good idea.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`List<T>` already implements `Collection<T>` - why would you need to create a new one?

```
Collection<T> collection = myList;
```

The error message is absolutely right - you can't directly instantiate an interface. If you want to create a *copy* of the existing list, you could use something like:

```
Collection<T> collection = new ArrayList<T>(myList);
```

Comment: When i do Collection<T> collection = new ArrayList<T>(myList);
after i put my list in my Object
obj.setMyCollection(collection );
or in my obj the collection is define Collection not ArrayList so when i want to see the result i have an error

Comment: @Mercer what is the signature of the method you're calling? A List should work on setMyCollection(Collection collection), but not if it's e.g. setMyCollection(Map collection) :) And if it's setMyCollection(List collection) then you should put something in that's declared a List: List collection = new ArrayList(); (removed generics to shorten it)

Answer (score 6):

Casting never needs a `new`:

```
Collection<T> collection = myList;
```

You don't even make the cast explicit, because `Collection` is a super-type of `List`, so it will work just like this.

Comment: when i do this , i have an error
Type mismatch: Can not convert List <T> in  Collection<T>

Comment: @Mercer: are you talking about `java.util.List` here? Could you give us some context (how is `<T>` defined, for example)?

Comment: @Mercer: Please provide a short but *complete* example then.

Comment: i do this 
Collections.sort(new ArrayList<Client>(product.getClient()));
but in my obj product i have this
public void setClient(Collection<Client> produitEvolution) {
this.client= client;
}
public Collection<Client> getClient() {
return client;
}

Answer (score 3):

There have multiple solusions to convert list to a collection

Solution 1

```
List<Contact> CONTACTS = new ArrayList<String>();
// fill CONTACTS
Collection<Contact> c = CONTACTS;
```

Solution 2

```
private static final Collection<String> c = new ArrayList<String>(
                                                Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
```

Solution 3

```
private static final Collection<Contact> = new ArrayList<Contact>(
                       Arrays.asList(new Contact("text1", "name1")
                                     new Contact("text2", "name2")));
```

Solution 4

```
List<? extends Contact> col = new ArrayList<Contact>(CONTACTS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your code, it's a bit hard to answer your question, but based on all the info here, I believe the issue is you're trying to use Collections.sort passing in an object defined as Collection, and sort doesn't support that.

First question. Why is client defined so generically? Why isn't it a List, Map, Set or something a little more specific?

If client was defined as a List, Map or Set, you wouldn't have this issue, as then you'd be able to directly use Collections.sort(client).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

First Collection is class Interface and you can not instantiate. [Collection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)

List [Ver APi](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is also an interface class.

It may be so

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
```

ver [enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

```
Collection collection= Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
```